# Can we upload a video file using jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I need to test load on video files uploaded using jmeter.
Can we upload a video file in jmeter ?
If so can any one guide me with actual steps.

Thanks,
joe

Comment: try this https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter & https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter

Answer (score 1):

You can mimic uploading of any file using JMeter, just mind the following:

1. In the HTTP Request sampler switch to "Files Upload" tab and provide the following:

   - Relative or full path to your video
   - Parameter name ([HTML input of "file" type](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_fileupload.asp) name attribute)
   - Video file [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type)
2. Make sure you select "POST" from the "Method" dropdown and tick `Use multipart/form-data for POST` box

   [image: JMeter Video Upload]

The easiest way is just [recording your file upload scenario](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) with [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), just remember to put the file you're trying to upload into JMeter's "bin" folder.